# Bot can't create tables automatically and user exists (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, psycopg2, telebot

Bot can't create tables automatically and user can't use the start button twice because user exists..

```
import psycopg2
bot = TeleBot("590----86:AAF9_DU9F_6----rvls26HgJMzHyJJpY")
```

I don't know what I didn't do !

```
def connect_to_db():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
    return conn
def insert_user_data(user_id, join_date, user_info):
    conn = connect_to_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO users (user_id, join_date, user_info) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(query, (user_id, join_date, user_info))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    join_date = message.date
    user_info = f"{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}"
    insert_user_data(user_id, join_date, user_info)
    bot.reply_to(message, "User information has been stored in the database.")
bot.polling()
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: just check inside of `insert_user_data` if the user with the user id already exists, and if it does just return and let your code pretend that it was created

Comment: Elaborate more bro  about that above answer